# Concatenate chunk containg headers to another chunk in h264

Tags: node.js, video, ffmpeg

I'm trying to extract thumbnails from a torrent stream by downloading the first couple of chunks to get the headers, another set of chunks from the middle and then concat them to have a single video file.

For this I'm using nodejs but I'm having trouble with the concatenation part. Obviously the headers include the length of the video so if I simply concat another chunk to the end of the headers chunk, it won't work.

In other words, I have 2 chunks of a video file: The first one contains the headers and some material and the other one is fully composed of a video stream. I want to combine the two to form a single video file
So my question is how can I make this work properly if at all?

Answer (score 0):

I found out that this is actually not possible. It has something to do with the encoded stream and I can't simply make a sparse file out of the two chunks